# How to filter wordpress the_date() and get_the_date() functions to show only year that a post was published

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, posts

I'm using the shortcodes ultimate plugin that allows me to display "post data." in the wordpress widgets area.

In this case, I'm trying to display the date each post was published, and it seems that this data is being pulled using the functions I listed above. I'm not sure, but that's my best guess.

I only want to show the year the post was published, not the month, day, and time. The shortcode workbox allows me to add a filter for this purpose, but I'm clueless as to which one will get the job done. This is a screenshot of the shortcode workbox with filter options: https://prnt.sc/1q67x0x

Answer (score 2):

Respectfully, a few points to improve the quality of your question which will help you get your problem solved sooner!

> - Please don't include some random weird looking link(s) in your question and expect people to click on it!
> - Also "I'm using a shortcodes plugin that allows me to display post data." is extremely unclear and not reproducible, so when you're using a plugin and ask for help please feel free to mention its name so that people could take a look and reproduce your problem/question!

Now let's talk about `get_the_date` function. This function will take two arguments:

- Format, which accepts string and is Optional PHP date format and it defaults to the 'date_format' option.
- Post ID, which is the post id and it defaults to current post.

> [`get_the_date`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/)

So in order to get only the year in a typical wordpress loop, you could pass `Y` into the format argument like so:

```php
echo get_the_date('Y');
```

For more info on `date and time formatting` in wordpress you could read the docs!

> [Formatting Date and Time<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/)

---

**Shortcodes Ultimate plugin date time formatting**

Your shortcode would be:

```php
[su_post field="post_modified" post_type="post" filter="my_custom_date_filter"]
```

and your filter function would be:

```php
function my_custom_date_filter($value)
{
  return date("Y", strtotime($value));
}
```

For example if your post was published `2020-12-06`, then the filter will only return the year `2020`.

Comment: I appreciate your input! Forgive me, I'm extremely new here and below novice level in technical skills. I edited my question per your recommendations. Were you brave enough to click on my screenshot link ? When I copy and paste the echo argument into my filter as shown in the screenshot, it has no result. I'm doing this all from the frontend since the shortcodes ultimate plugin allows for it...